# Java 7 - "Comparison method violates its general contract!"

Tags: java, collections, comparable

Everything seemed to be running okay (for several days), but I ran into an issue only once and having a really hard time to reproduce the problem.

"Comparison method violates its general contract!" was thrown and completely caught me off guard. I have the following:

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<Chromosome> {

public int compare(Chromosome c1, Chromosome c2){

    return c1.compareTo(c2);
}

}
```

My Chromosome class:

```
public class Chromosome implements Comparable<Chromosome>{

private double rank;

//bunch of methods...

@Override public int compareTo(Chromosome c){

    final int BEFORE = -1;
    final int EQUAL = 0;
    final int AFTER = 1;

    if (this.getRank() == c.getRank()) //getRank() simply returns a double value 'rank'
        return EQUAL;

    else if (this.getRank() < c.getRank())
            return BEFORE;

    else  //i.e. (this.getRank() > c.getRank())
        return AFTER;   

}
```

I have an ArrayList and I used both Collections.sort(MyList) and Collections.sort(MyList, Collections.reverseOrder()). They're still working fine up till now. I just ran into that error only once out of 100's of run. Is there something wrong with this implementation?

Comment: Are any of the double values NaN?

Comment: Probably result of `0.0/0.0` or something like that.

Comment: Also your compareTo method could simply be, `return Double.compare(this.rank, c.rank);`. And your custom comparator is useless since its calling `compareTo` on the Chromosome instances itself.

Comment: Is it possible that rank is NaN?  NaN is neither greater than, less than, or equal to NaN.  See [the answers to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values) for an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java 7 has changed the behavior of their sorting algorithms a bit. They now throw an Exception if a violation of the general contract for the `compareTo` method is detected. You can read about that contract's properties for example [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

In general it could be violated for example in case that it would resolve to a < b and b < a. If this was detected before Java 7, it was just silently ignored. Now an Exception will be thrown.

If you want to use the old behaviour, you may use the following:

`System.setProperty("java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort", "true");`

But I don't encourage you to do this. You should just change your implementation to the standard implementation of double comparison via [`Double.compare(a, b)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare%28double,%20double%29). This implementation correctly deals with infinity and NaN values for doubles.

Furthermore if your `Comparator` just delegates to the `compareTo` method, it can be discarded in general.

Comment: Thanks. I'll just use Double.compare() instead. I haven' run into the issue again, so it's quite strange. 

Also, I'm not sure I understand the example you've given which violates the contract. How can I have two double values a and b, such that a < b and at the same time b < a?

Comment: @wFateem It was just an example of how it could be violated. There are actually several other rules that have to be followed. For example the one of symmetry. a == a is supposed to be always true. But the IEEE 754 standard which defines how doubles work, states that Double.NaN should be != Double.NaN, which does violate the rule of symmetry. That's one of the things that Double.compare(...) fixes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. Appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Possibly that one of your parameter might be due to positive or negative infinity i.e. dividing by zero. Also don't rely upon == on double values. You should just use:

```
return Double.compare(this.getRank(), c.getRank());
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the Double.compare() probably makes more sense to use that instead. 
It can't be an issue of a division by zero. Rank is only the value returned by a neural network based on pixel values of an image (int between 0 and 255). A sigmoid function is used by the neural network.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please close this question by accepting the answer so it can help other's with similar issue.